# Desktop Bridge - References don't work in 17134

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, uwp, desktop-bridge

Calling a UWP API like:

```
var channel = await Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

At compile time I get the error:

```
The type name 'PushNotificationChannelManager' could not be found in the namespace 'Windows.Networking.PushNotifications'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' Consider adding a reference to that assembly
```

This happens just creating a new WPF app and adding references to:

1. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade\Windows.WinMD`
2. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`

Comment: Wrong windows.winmd file.  They did not think versioning through really well and it got messy at build 16299.  I don't have 17134 installed yet so can't be sure, life's too short to keep up, but you surely need to reference the one in Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\Facade\

Comment: I got the same result with the one in Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0\Facade\

Comment: Please try to install the [UWPDesktop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop/10.0.14393.3) package to your project using the NuGet Package Manager.

Answer (score -1):

This topic explains how to add the correct references - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

Comment: Adding the reference to Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd the error disappears, but causes a cycle on IAsyncOperation.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure there. Have you set the "Copy Local" field of the *.winmd files to "False"?

Comment: Yes but nothing change